# unable to locate package php7.0 and libapache2-mod-php7.0

Tags: mysql, lamp, php7

I've just downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to install PHP 7, but I keep getting the following error:

```
unable to locate package php7.0libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

I tried running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

I've been searching for a while and cannot find a miracle to help.

Comment: please use `sudo apt` not `sudo apt-get` and lets see.

Comment: Hi George - I've run `sudo apt` on both the update and php7 commands and it's still unable to locate the package.

Comment: try this `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I've run the `add-apt-repository

Comment: I've run the `add-apt-repository` command and the update. I assume the repository command installed a version of PHP for me?

Comment: search for php7 with `apt search php7` see if you see it in the results.

Comment: No it didn't now do the search, then if you see it re-run your install commands

Comment: It's all working now, cheers George!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears you are missing the *repository* for *php7*.

Adding the *php7 ppa*:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
2. Then update:

   - `sudo apt-get update`
3. Now do a search to confirm *php7* is there:

   - `sudo apt search php7`
4. Now install the *php7* package:

   - `sudo apt install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0`

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a typo in your command, there is no existent package named `php7.0libapache2-mod-php7.0`, i think maybe a *bad copy-paste* led you to a wrong package name, correct names for such package could be `libapache2-mod-php7.0` or simply `libapache2-mod-php`.

Also I do not agree too much with adding a *ppa* as a solution for this, since it can be done with ubuntu's official packages.

Since Xenial *(16.04)*, `php7.x` is the default version, supported by Canonical, and has complete `php7.x` stack support without adding an "untrusted" ppa.

In practical terms it means that if you install `php` (*and/or `libapache2-mod-php` in your case*) *metapackages*, the subyacent working version of php and its libraries are going to be always from 7.x branch on Ubuntu 16.04+. Simply issuing `sudo apt install php php-mysql php-curl php-json php-cgi libapache2-mod-php` on a terminal, will led your system to a fully working `php7.0` environment meeting your requirements.

I only recommend using *ondrej's ppa*, which otherwise i have used intensely, if you want or need *unsupported* php versions (`php5.6` on 16.04 or 14.04, `php7.0` on 14.04, etc).

Comment: Please look at the process that led to adding the said _ppa_. We tried checking with the normal _package_ that should be in his Ubuntu and was not seen after we went for the _ppa_. Adding the _ppa_ was not the first option.

Comment: Yes but I really think that the desired package is `libapache2-mod-php7.0` which is indeed on main repos. I think the OP had a typo copy pasting from somewhere (or somethinglike that) and ended with `php7.0libapache2-mod-php` a package name wich doesnt exist, even on mentioned _ondrej's ppa_.

Comment: I disagree with you on that. I saw the _typo_ in the _title_ but which was clear in the __body of the OP__. And again he tried installing via `apt install` and it returned nothing so my thinking is that he is missing something (which is perfectly normal as these things happen) so I went for the other option. Now if you could provide steps to how he should proceed with getting it from the _official channel_ I will gladly remove my answer. __You should have asked if he had actually typed it correctly and if I confirmed that before giving my answer__ before claiming he did.

Comment: __Please give a solution to his problem not a suggestion to it. Suggestions don't solve problems, solutions do!__

Comment: Sorry but I only wish to contribute with my opinion as with some experience with webservers i went into dependecy hell with that certain ppa. And sorry again I thought it was clear that simply issuing `sudo apt install php php-mysql php-curl php-json php-cgi libapache2-mod-php` will end with desired package versions. I'll update my answer too to make it more visible.

Comment: There are things that are passed in as _comments_ and things that are _answers_. Yours is a comment not an answer. If the OP owner were to follow your post would he solve his problem ? That's the question to ask. But of course you are free to make your input but please let it be done the right way.

Comment: I reiterate on my apologies, I simply tried to contribute my personal experience and opinion, and again i would like to explain that I thought the answer was clear enough indicating that since 16.04 the default version of `php` and all its libraries is 7.x. And maybe i also missed to warn the OP about the possible typo in the title. Thanks for your tips pointing me into the right way.